# Unable to convert Adobe Type 1 font to ttf/woff format successfully

Tags: php, html, fonts, adobe, webfonts

I have one document written using one Adobe Type 1 font. Now I want to show its contain in a html website. I tried to convert this font to ttf/woff format but all online available tools either failing during conversion or after converting when I load the same doc file (removing existing Adobe Type 1 font and installing converted font), it does not show the content properly

Example: while converting using fontforge tool, it says error detected. Err: "Missing points at extrema, Bad private dictionary, there is another gylph in the font with this unicode code point"

Kindly suggest alternative tool which can convert
Adobe Type 1 font successfully or any other alternative by which I can display Adobe Type 1 font based content in a html website. Thank you

Comment: What is fontforge? Is it a php tool?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [makeotf](https://adobe-type-tools.github.io/afdko/MakeOTFUserGuide.html) (from Adobe's [AFDKO](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/afdko) suite of tools) but from what you describe it sounds like there might be some errors in the Type1 font itself that are the root problem. "Missing points at extrema" and "another glyph in the font with this Unicode codepoint" should not be a deal breakers, but "Bad private dictionary" might be.

The conversion would be from Type1 to OTF, which, if successful, is readily convertible to woff/woff2 for use in a website by any number of online or other conversion tools.